# FTP account creation through front end

Tags: linux, django, ftp, freebsd

I am working on a file upload project where users will be able to upload large files. When the user creates/register as a member I want a FTP account to automatically be created on the server and the login information should be provided to the user.

I somehow need to be able to keep track on each users bandwidth, upload/download usage etc...

What would be a good and fairly secure way to accomplish this and how would you do it?

I am developing this project on a server running FreeBSD, using Django for the Web-development.

Appreciate your input...

Comment: This obviously depends on which FTP server you are planning to use.

Answer (score 1):

You may use proftpd. It may use radius/mysql for users.
[ProFTP site](http://www.proftpd.org/)